Ошибка при входе в приложение chatGPT на IOS
По инструкции создал новый apple id, установил из app store приложение chat gpt, но при входе в аккаунт появляется ошибка. Время на американское менял, телефон перезагружал, впн использую (пробовал и американские сервера и неамериканские)
Текст ошибки:

Войти в систему не удалось Что-то пошло не так. Убедитесь, что дата и
время на вашем устройстве установлены правильно. Проверьте, что ваше
интернет-соединение стабильно, затем перезапустите приложение и
повторите попытку.
(code:866A5248-D41C-4F07-B179-9F98DE04C049,AP|Error,400)


Попробовал очередной vpn (хотя до этого испытал штук 7, все рабочие) - помогло, использовал matreshkaVPN.
